# How to check a Certificate is in default cacerts

Tags: java, ssl

A client provide me with a HTTPS URL for a service call. I need to make a  request to that URL. I know that if the certificate of that URL is from a common provider chances are that it's already available on the default java truststore **cacerts**.

However I am unsure how to check whether I need to import the certificate or not.  How can I check whether a certificate from a website is already in default java truststore \jre1.8\lib\security\cacerts?

Comment: Nothing unclear here. Poorly phrased, and betrays a misunderstanding of the problem, but the overall objective is clear.

Answer (score 30):

You can inspect (list) certificates in your cacert keystore using the Java `keytool` command.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/cacerts
```

`keytool` has to be in your path, or can be found in the `bin` directory of your Java installation (e.g. `C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8/bin/keytool.exe`).

Comment: But that won't tell him whether the server certificate is trusted, if it's signed by a CA. He would have to check the entire chain.

Comment: Correct, although that isn't the question he asked.

Comment: Well, he is really asking whether he needs to import it or not.

Comment: "So how can I check whether a certificate from a website is already in java default truststore \jre1.8\lib\security\cacerts or not?"

Comment: 'However I am unsure how to check whether I need to import the certificate or not.' We can quote bits of the question to each other all day, but it's perfectly clear what his actual objective is.

Comment: 'However I am unsure how to check whether I need to import the certificate or not' - Indeed, he can check by listing the certificates in the keystore, who would have thought?

Comment: if it is asking for a password consider adding `-storepass changeit` to the command.

Answer (score 5):

Just try to connect to it with `URL` and `HttpsURLConnection`, going at least as far as getting the response code, and no fancy trust managers or anything. If it's trusted, you won't have a problem.

Your terminology is astray. All certificates are public. If it's a *CA-signed* certificate, signed by a *CA* whose certificate is in `cacerts`, you don't need to import it.

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach to list certificates in cacerts is

```
keytool -v -list -cacerts -storepass changeit
```